# unable to read the data

Tags: java, inputstream, java-io

I am trying to read the content from a specific URL for which i have access too.I was facing issues. So i just started with the basic example taken from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html)

I'm facing ConnectionException.

```
public class UrlReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            System.setProperty("http.proxyHost","http://www.oracle.com/");
            System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8081");

        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

                return new PasswordAuthentication("doaminName\\username","password".toCharArray());
            }
        });

        URL url = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                con.getInputStream()));

        // Read it ...
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);

        in.close();


       /* URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();*/
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
```

I HAVE followed some online links to resolve it but with no success.
Had any one faced this kind of issues while working from **work laptop**.**I want to connect to some URL and read the content from that URL using java.**

Comment: Have you tried `https://www.oracle.com/`? That page is https.

Comment: Yes, same exception Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect. Is this because i'm trying from my work laptop which might have some firewall(not sure). @GlenPierce

Comment: www.oracle.com is not an HTTP proxy host, and www.oracle.com:8081 is not an HTTP proxy port. Trying to connect to a host using itself as a proxy doesn't make any sense. 'Connection refused' does not mean 'unable to read the data'. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost","http://www.oracle.com/");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8081");
```

Oracle does not provide an HTTP proxy service on port 8081, or probably at all, to the outside world. These two lines of code are meaningless, especially as your target URL is also www.oracle.com. Remove them.

Comment: if you see my code in my post, initially I tried with the commented code where I have not used System.setProperty..I was facing the same issue. Is that because of some firewall??

Comment: Really? Same issue? Connection refused? To a public web server that I can access from this browser? I don't think so. Unless it's your *own* firewall getting in the way.

Comment: Yes, i believe its my own firewall as i'm using company's(work) laptop. Is there any way to resolve this ?

Comment: Most probably your company provides an HTTP proxy. Find out what it is and set the associated system properties to that. Not to the target.